# why typeof(Inf) is double?

Tags: r, double

In R, why does `typeof(Inf)` return `double`?
Does R consider Infinity a real number or just a number?

```
x=1
xx=0
y=x/xx
typeof(y)
```

the answer is `"double"`

Thank you

Comment: You divide two doubles. Did you expect the arithmetic operation to change the type?

Comment: @Roland Err, yes: `typeof(1L / 2L)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know. I'm trying to find out what exactly OP is asking us and what they are confused about. I find the question quite unclear.

Comment: I dont understand why R cnoseder a/0 is Inf and not NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well generally, because *any* number literal in R has type `double`, unless it ends by `L`:

```
> typeof(1)
double
> typeof(NA_real_)
double
> typeof(1L)
integer
```

And more specifically, because [`Inf` is a special value that can only be stored in a floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity), not in an integer number.

Comment: not necessarily: `1:5` for instance has type `integer`.

Comment: @JDL True, but it’s not a number literal. ;-) And the type depends on `:`, which can be overridden (case in point, in my interactive R sessions the type of `1:5` is `xrange` because I override `:`).

Comment: Fine, fine... `NA_integer_` :P